# Null space and related question

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose vectors $v_i, i=1, ..., p$ is a basis of the null space of $m\times n$ matrix $B$. If $x\in \mathbb{R}^n, <x, v_i>=0, i=1, ..., p$, then there exists a vector $y$ such that

$x=B^\intercal y$.

How to prove this assertion if valid? I haven't find out a clear path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I leave you to prove that the null space of any matrix $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the column space of $A^T$.

Using thay property, proving your assertion is straightforward.